# Find the number of elements in range of $g(f(x))$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be bijective functions where $f:(a,b,c,d)\rightarrow(1,2,3,4)$ and $g:(3,4,5,6)\rightarrow(w,x,y,z)$ respectively.Then,find the number of elements in range of g(f(x)).

I have a doubt.Will this function even be defined?I mean the range of $f$ does not coincide with domain of $g$.Can someone please clear this conceptual doubt?

Comment: It can be thought in another way ie domain of f is codomain of g

Comment: Right.But is it defined even if domain of g does not contain some values in range of f ? Do you know of a source stating it? @ArchisWelankar

Comment: I don't know a source but we are taught in class the condition  that range of $f(x)$ should be a subset of codomian of g

Comment: But here range of f(x) should is not a subset of codomian of g

Comment: $g(f(x))$ is only defined for $x\in\{a,b\}$ (assuming $f(a)=1$ etc). So the range of $g(f(x))$ is $\{w,x\}$ (again assuming $g(3)=w$ etc).

Answer (score 1):

The composition of $g$ and $f$ is defined.

Let's examine the definition of a composite function.

Let $u$ and $v$ be any two functions.  We define a new function $u \circ v$, the *composition* of $u$ and $v$, by
$$(u \circ v)(x) = u(v(x))$$
The domain of $u \circ v$ is the set of $x$ in the domain of $v$ such that $v(x)$ is in the domain of $u$.

Since $f: (a, b, c, d) \to (1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $g(3, 4, 5, 6) \to (w, x, y, z)$, only those elements in the domain of $f$ that map to $3$ and $4$ lie in the domain of $g \circ f$.  Since $f$ is a bijection, it has an inverse function.  Therefore, the domain of $g \circ f$ is $\{f^{-1}(3), f^{-1}(4)\}$.  Use the fact that $f$ and $g$ are both bijections to determine the number of elements in the range of $g \circ f$.